# does innerHTML not evaluate javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying out a technique where I break my code up into individual files (so that a page that might have a bunch of different pieces is now multiple files rather than one humongous HTML page) and use ajax to load them and then set the contents as innerHTML to some parent div.  This makes for very clean code and works nicely in seemingly all modern browsers, but I just noticed that when the external page contains a `<script>` tag, the javascript that's in that tag is just ignored (not parsed and loaded into the parent page's javascript context) so the methods and variables that exist in these external snippets are simply missing.

I have kludged a work around where I read the script tag's contents in and then `eval()` the whole thing, and that works... however, I'm curious if I'm overlooking some more native mechanism for including the script in these external files, or if this approach is really the only one there is to achieve my goals.

TIA

Comment: Is the `script` tag not present in the DOM, or does the code in it not execute?

Comment: @JanDvorak "Added 2 characters in body." What about the `eval()`? This seems a bit pedantic.

Comment: @WaleedKhan, the ~<script>~ tag is present in my external snippets. So, the code that's read in via AJAX is valid HTML (including valid javascript). The whole thing is retrieved in the ajax request and then loaded via innerHTML into an encasing DIV. However, the javascript isn't evaluated at the time of being set in the innerHTML (or ever).  So, as I said, I'm manually parsing that chunk out of the incoming text and eval()ing it but that seems ugly to me.

Comment: @JanDvorak, by all means :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a job for `innerHTML`. You should probably load the external file as a DOM object (which is the origin of the `XMLHTTPRequest` name) so the `script` tag is turned into the proper object before getting added.

A quick experiment with Firefox using jQuery (on this page, heh) shows that `innerHTML` will add a script element that doesn't get executed, whereas this does execute:

```
$( 'body' ).append( $('<script>console.log( "hello, world!" );</script>' ) );
```

Comment: interesting... so... I'm quite familiar with XMLHTTPRequest, but in this instance was using `jQuery.get()` to achieve the same result. Should I switch back to straight javascript for this or is there a jQuery analog that I can leverage?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Just specify `'XML'` as the [last argument](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to `jQuery.get()`.

Comment: ah.. I think we were typing at the same time. So you're saying I should use append instead of innerHTML?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Use whatever you want… `innerHTML` is DOM, not a jQuery API so I assumed you weren't using jQ. To get the same semantics, you could use `$.replaceAll`.